# Search form block only appear for administrarors

Tags: search

I have a site with three different languages on it. for a while we had a search bottom on the English site. I wanted to be on all three languages. after playing around with it, it now appears in all languages, but only for administrators. how can I make it appear for users as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's about the **permissions**. Give the users (anonymous user / authenticated user) the search permission (also), which you can do after navigating to `admin/people/permissions`.